# Mac keyboard won't type letter 'c' only in some cases, also switching keyboards. No problems with the same keyboard connected to a PC

Tags: mac, keyboard, typing

I've got a strange problem with my Mac keyboard on an IMac, year 2008:

I cannot type letter 'c' in password fields, gmail website and other specific circumstances.
I've tried switching the keyboards, but nothing changes.

Any of my two wired keyboards works fine on a Windows 7 PC.

Is there a software setting that can compromise my keyboard typing?
My OSX version is 10.6.7

Comment: try another browser. Maybe the problem is there.

Comment: Yes, The problem is only in google chrome. Google chrome additionally cannot update. I resolved installing a newer OSX version